# Latex indent is messing up the characters ä, ö and ü

Tags: formatting, latexindent

I have the a problem when formatting my latex documents with "latexindent", because the german characters ä, ö and ü are getting replaced with wrong characters.

For example I have the following line in my latex document:

```
\title{Zusätzliche Beteiligung}
```

After formatting the document, it becomes:

```
\title{ZusÃ¤tzliche Beteiligung}
```

Is there any option I can set, that prevents latexindent from doing this? I could not find any solutions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like a file encoding problem. Is your file UTF-8 or some other encoding? I would expect UTF-8, but if you're using a different encoding, then that's likely the problem. You can specify the encoding that `latexindent` assumes in `indentconfig.yaml`. See §4 of the manual.

Comment: File should be UTF-8, `file` command shows the following output: `LaTeX 2e document text, Unicode text, UTF-8 text`, i am writing with neovim. In my indentconfig.yaml in my home directory i only have the following line: `encoding: UTF8`, but the problem is still there :(

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the issue.

Comment: How are you invoking `latexindent`?

Comment: Okay I checked it again by using latexindent via the command line. Here it works. The problem appears only by using latexindent via the Neovim formatting Plugin "conform.nvim". I guess I have to check what happens there. Thank you all.

Comment: But the problem is only appearing if using latexindent. Other formatters work correctly.

Comment: apologies, this is related to `STDIN`; this bug was introduced by V3.23.7. i'm working on a fix. in the mean time, roll back to an earlier version if you need immediate fix.

Comment: Alternatively use v3.23.7 from the command line and it should be fine

Comment: V3.23.8 released and should resolve this https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/releases/tag/V3.23.8

Comment: @cmhughes It works! Thank you! :)

Comment: Perhaps post an answer here? It's OK, and encouraged, to self answer

Comment: @cmhughes The OP answered as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @cmhughes said in the comments, the bug was instroduced in version 3.23.7 and has been fixed in version 3.23.8.

Comment: ah OK in that case I think I'll delete my answer, while it's not actually wrong it doesn't really help